# Highcharts move xAxis down / off of chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I am working on legacy code from a previous developer and they used highcharts.js (v3.0.1). The xAxis is landing within the graph ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxQzq.png)) and I can't sort out why this is. I tried to recreate this in jsfiddle but I can't get that axis to move.  I thought that maybe it was a bug in the version but I can't get it to replicate so I'm thinking that is has to be something within the sites own CSS that is manipulating it, however, it's built with g, rect, and text tags which I don't see in any of the custom CSS files.

I've looked through other Highchart.js posts on here but I haven't seen this issue posted yet. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

EDIT: I forgot to mention this but all the usernames are centered [text-center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj5dR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check exactly how xAxis labels are aligned. As I can see they are rotated vertically so it is important to set appropriate labels align property:

```
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Apple', 'Samsung', 'Dell', 'Lenovo'],
    labels: {
      align: 'left',
      rotation: 90
    }
  }
```

Demo: 
 
- labels align center: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/29b4qejc/ 
- labels align left: https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/56evyrxj/

Api reference: 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.align

Comment: YES! This was the issue! I kept searching for axis alignment and I didn't think to look for label alignment. After doing a grep search I found that outside the Highcharts.theme it was calling for align:'center'. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

are you use the labels padding ? 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.padding

Be sure that the number is greater than 0.

Comment: Yeah Is looked through that as well. The thing that is throwing my off the most is that somehow the axis row is centered and I can't find any sort of text-center within the API. I've added the additional screenshot to the original post.